# Checking if AWS SQS message was received by queue and it is pending to read by listener or already read by listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sqs-fifo, sqslistener

I am new to AWS and trying to create SQS message. I am using existing working code. I can see in the log that message is created successfully. I am logging SendMessageResult messageId for debugging purpose.
Now I am trying to check if msg is pending to read/listen by listener or it is already read/listen by listener. I tried using AWS console to check the same but not able find any detail. I dont have access to listener logs so not able to check listener logs.

Where I can check if msg is pending to read or it is already read by listener?